# Image onmouseover/onmouseout doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

i am trying to achieve an image change when i enter with the mouse cursor inside the container box where the image is placed. Locally everything works perfect but on a demo server for example i have to click inspect element on every box for it to start working and also after i do this sometimes it works and sometimes not. I've added the jquery online library in the head section of my page.  Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li> 
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/img1.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/img2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/img1.png'"  alt="img">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/img1.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/img2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/img1.png'"  alt="img">
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think this is because your images takes too long to load and you need to wait or preload images using JS at page load

Comment: Does img1 work at all on the server without inspect? My guess is your img path is not correct

Comment: On another note, I don't think your current solution requires jQuery.

Comment: Jquery isn't some magic piece of software. You have to actually use it in your code, which you currently aren't.

Comment: jQuery has a nice `hover()` method you could use [http://api.jquery.com/hover/](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Does img1 work at all on the server without inspect? My guess is your img path is not correct – Huangism

yes,img1 loads but the second image when i enter the box doesn't appear

Comment: @dreamweiver - the OP says `I've added the jquery online library in the head section of my page` he has also included a jQuery tag in the question.

Comment: @dreamweiver Why would using jQuery result in a performance issue? Something written (well) in pure JS would likely be faster than the jQuery alternative, but the difference would be negligible in most cases.

Comment: @Zhihao:  Yes obviosuly jquery is way more powerful and simple compared to javascript. but i dont see any jquery in the code posted by OP. inclusion of something which is never used will obviously result in page slow down.

Comment: @dreamweiver Seems like I misunderstood what you meant then, as it sounded jQuery leading to poor performance was suggested. I agree with you that it would increase page load times. I'd just like to clarify the different between page load time and performance though, as JS performance should not be impacted by simply loading another library (especially one that isn't used).

Comment: @Zhihao: on the first load of the page , the load time will be much higher compared to 2...n number of loads, as most of the browser cache the js .as a matter of fact the performance will be a issue if multiple clients access the page for the first time, as there will be high traffic in downloading the js on each of the clients browser. client side scripting will be much faster and simple with jquery rather than with raw javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the filename.Use:

```
<ul>
<li> 
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img1.png" onmouseover="this.src=this.src.replace('img1','img2')" onmouseout="this.src=this.src.replace('img2','img1')"  alt="img">
  </a>
</li>
<li> 
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img1.png" onmouseover="this.src=this.src.replace('img1','img2')" onmouseout="this.src=this.src.replace('img2','img1')"  alt="img">
  </a>
</li>
```